# Extracting words between two strings in ProperCase and Line breaks

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following dataframe sorry for the mess (it was scraped from a website)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TEXT': ['Product Type:\n \n \n Fish\n \n \n \n \n Variety:\n \n \n Salmon\n \n \n \n \n Style:\n \n \n FROZEN\n \n \n \n \n Shape:\n \n \n Sliced\n \n \n \n \n Part:\n \n \n Fillet\n \n \n','Product Type:\n \n \n Fish\n \n \n \n \n Variety:\n \n \n Salmon\n \n \n \n \n Style:\n \n \n FROZEN\n \n \n \n \n Freezing Process:\n \n \n IQF\n \n \n \n \n Shape:\n \n \n Block\n \n \n \n \n Part:\n \n \n Body\n \n \n \n \n Certification:\n \n \n BRC, FDA, HACCP\n']})
```

and I want to extract the different parameters. For example,
I would like the output to be

```
df['ProductType']="Fish"
```

I tried this:

```
df['ProductType']=df['TEXT'].str.extract("(?=Type\:)(.*)(?=Variety\:)").astype(str)
```

but it justs outputs NaNs.
Sorry if it's too obvious, I'm starting with regex today

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Preferably use a more obvious and less noisy input string that still represents your data, if possible.

Comment: sure, I'll fix that. thanks!

Comment: `"(?s)Type:(.*?)Variety:"`